# titanium appcelerator - how do i specify which version of the sdk to use?

Tags: appcelerator

1. with titanium appcelerator, how do i specify I want to use version X in my project?
2. how do i know *which* is the latest version of Appcelerator that I have to use?

Comment: why did you ask and then answer your own question?

Comment: @AaronSaunders ?? Check the times bro. I asked the question, spent a while trying to work it out, then because nobody had answered, I answered the question. For... The Future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oho.

So in the tiapp.xml file there is this entry:

```
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    ... other stuff here
    <sdk-version>3.1.1.GA</sdk-version>
```

You'll be wanting to edit that value to the value of the titanium sdk you'd like to use. I uh, i don't quite understand why the "GA" is there, but that appears to be on all the 3.X version\

As for the latest version, i'm unsure. I don't know quite how to check what version you have available.

As for what version Titanium is up to, go to the [titanium api homepage](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/) and then select the link "QuickStart" - it is a tab-like thingy.

On *that* page, search for the words "compatibility matrix", and click on that link. I didn't post the link because the simple folks who mind the Titanium website might change it.

On *that* link, there are a few tables listing what version of the sdk needs which version of android/ios etc. You'll find the latest version they're using there.

Good luck, warrior.